# Fetch Firebase Crashlytics logs using Github Actions

Tags: github-actions, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I am using Github actions in my project for CI/CD. I want to fetch top crashes from Firebase crashlytics but somehow I can't seem to find a way to do it. Basically, it would be a cron job, I don't need help in creating a cron job using Github actions, I know how to do it. I need help in how can I connect to Firebase crashlytics and fetch top crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting the Crashlytics data into BigQuery is the only way to access this information. From there you could transfer it to your Github actions or other environment. This will also allow you to create your own queries.

Here is the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export) for this.